# EclipseLink pagination and Oracle ROWNUM

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, pagination, eclipselink

Using EclipseLink JPA 2.5.2 with specification and pagination I have a problem regarding the way Oracle ROWNUM is being executed. The EclipseLink generated query is the following:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               ROWNUM rnum
          FROM (SELECT   t0.ID,
                         t0.participantidentity_id,
                         t0.submitteddate
                    FROM delegation t4,
                         meeting t3,
                         meetinggroup t2,
                         participantidentity t1,
                         reimbursement t0,
                         userdata ud
                   WHERE t0.current_id IS NULL
                     AND t1.activeparticipant_id IS NOT NULL
                     AND t2.responsibleservice_id IN (74)
                     AND t1.ID = t0.participantidentity_id
                     AND t4.ID = t1.delegation_id
                     AND t3.ID = t4.meeting_id
                     AND t2.ID = t3.meetinggroup_id
                     AND t1.userdata_id = ud.ID
                ORDER BY t0.submitteddate ASC) a
         WHERE ROWNUM <= 25)
 WHERE rnum > 0
```

Running that query for the first page should return the rows between 0 and 25 and running the same query for second page should return the rows between 25 and 50.

The problem is that records from the first page also appear in the second page, I guess it is because the submitteddate can contain NULL values and the ORDER BY clause is not applied before the ROWNUM and the rnum conditions or something similar, I'm not sure because I'm a bit puzzled right now...

Could anybody explain me the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: That looks like the query for the first page; what is the query for the second page? Because as is, it will just return the same set of rows (assuming no new rows are added in between!)

Comment: Hi, the query for the second page just changes the limits 25 and 0 by the limits 50 and 25 respectively

Comment: I would guess the issue is that new rows have been added between requesting the first and second pages. IMO, you have two options - 1. set the isolation level to read only (see [the documentation for more info](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10005.htm)) or change the query so that it isn't paginated, and have EclipseLink pull the first 25 rows, then the next 25 etc as required from the cursor (I don't know anything about EclipseLink, so I don't know if this would be possible or not).

Comment: No new rows have been added because it is a local DB and I'm not even running the application, I'm just querying the DB with plain SQL. I only have 53 records in the table and that doesn't change, the only thing that changes is the result of the query depending on the upper and lower rownum limits.

Comment: Ok, then it sounds like you have an issue with your ordering - there are probably tied rows, meaning that different queries could return the rows in a different order. eg. for (col1, col2, col3) in ((1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2)), if you order by col1 only, the rows could be returned as: (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), or maybe (1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2). You'd have to introduce further columns to order on in the event of a tie.

Comment: You must use a unique value for your ordering otherwise it is non-deterministic.  Order by the ID value as well as the date so that you get the same ordering by the database no matter how many times you run the query.

Comment: Indeed @Chris, finally I decided to add a trailing order by clause by ID and now the results are correct no matter the top and bottom rownum limits I use.

Answer (score 0):

I did some sort of test based on above scenario--

```
CREATE TABLE T3(AA NUMBER(10),BB NUMBER(10),CC NUMBER(10),DD NUMBER(10));
INSERT INTO T3 VALUES (1,2,3,null);
INSERT INTO T3 VALUES (4,5,6,13);
INSERT INTO T3 VALUES (7,8,9,NULL);
INSERT INTO T3 VALUES (10,11,12,14);
```

and then--

```
 SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT
    a.*,
    rownum rnum
  FROM
    (SELECT aa AS a1,
      bb   AS a2,
      CC          AS A3,
      dd as a4
    FROM T3
    ORDER BY DD ASC) A
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 2
  )
WHERE rnum > 0;
```

this test is never returning duplicates.

So  please execute your below query

```
SELECT   t0.ID,
                             t0.participantidentity_id,
                             t0.submitteddate
                        FROM delegation t4,
                             meeting t3,
                             meetinggroup t2,
                             participantidentity t1,
                             reimbursement t0,
                             userdata ud
                       WHERE t0.current_id IS NULL
                         AND t1.activeparticipant_id IS NOT NULL
                         AND t2.responsibleservice_id IN (74)
                         AND t1.ID = t0.participantidentity_id
                         AND t4.ID = t1.delegation_id
                         AND t3.ID = t4.meeting_id
                         AND t2.ID = t3.meetinggroup_id
                         AND t1.userdata_id = ud.ID
                    ORDER BY t0.submitteddate ASC
```

And check if it is having any duplicates.

Also, try to use distinct key word at the start of your sql like `select distinct t0.ID...`

Comment: I have no duplicates in my rows. The solution was pointed out by @Chris in my initial question, adding an order by clause by ID solved the problem by removing the non-deterministic behavior of my initial query.